# What's the role of 了 in this sentence: 你要是喜欢我就给你买了

Tags: particles

Is it an aspect marker? Is it a specific grammatical construction with 就 or 要是? Is it there just for emphasis? I can't work it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

了 - is not a verb complement. It's a realis maker, that is, by adding 了 at the end of the verb you render it to reality and not to a probabilistic-theoretical suggestion. So, in OP case, 了 renders possible situation to absolute truth.

你要是喜欢我就给你买
*If you like it, I would buy it for you.* (talking about possible situation)

你要是喜欢我就给你买了
*Your liking is enough for me to buy it.* 
or
*If you like it, consider the buyng as done (that is, real).*
(buying for sure, no way back!)

Comment: You overstate 买了. To express "buying for sure, no way back!", you have to add some words to emphasize: eg. 你要是喜欢, 我就【 一定 】给你买！

Comment: No, no... 就 is the emphasis here... 就买了= buying it for sure!  就 should be translated as a kind of "AND" but with a hint of "already" (IMHO).
买了 without any emphasis will just mean that "the act of buying will/have/is taking place, without any indication that it is/was/will be complete or reach the goal.

Comment: 就 actually isn't that strong here. With a normal tone, 我就给你买了 is like saying "*so I'm gonna go ahead to get it (bought) for you*".

Comment: Well, maybe not strong, but some power is posessed by 就. 就 - is kind of a consequential AND. *Something, something.......... AND I'll buy it.* Well, those are details.

Comment: by the way. 谢谢 vs 谢谢了. How would one explain the difference? In "realis" maker view it's quiet easy. *thank you* vs *really thank you*

Comment: Regarding 谢谢 vs 谢谢了, I don't see much difference. Both can be interpreted as "*Thanks!*". In spoken, we frequently say 谢谢，谢了 or just 谢（especially in typing). I will take them all in the same degree of thankfulness, just like "*Thanks!*".

Answer (score 6):

I think the key is the usage of 了. In my opinion, 了 here works like a **result complement**,  which indicates **the status changed**.

Semantically, they(with or without 了) denote the same meaning.

我买 vs 我买了:

我买 is like saying "*I will buy*" in English.

我买了 is like "*I will have/get it bought*. The status changed from *not bought* to *bought*.

Another example is 我走 vs 我走了. 我走 is *I am going.* 我走了 is *I will be gone.* The status changed from *staying here* to *be gone*.

Hope this could help you out.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer imho.

Comment: 我买 differs from  我买了 in a complete different sence.  我买了 - is a situation which took, taking, will take place in reality, as a fact. But  我买 is a probability, dream, habitual situation.  我买  I usually buy, I might buy, The buying is a habit of mine... there are may translation to this pair.

Answer (score 3):

了 is used to indicate *completed* status, contrast with the current situation.

```
你要是喜欢我就给你买
If you like it, I would buy it for you.
(If you don't like it, I wouldn't buy it.)

你要是喜欢我就给你买了
If you like it, I would have bought it for you.
(You don't like it so I didn't buy it.)
```

Answer (score 1):

It's there for emphasis purpose, the sentence will have the same meaning even without 了. If translated to English, it would be something like this:

---

你要是喜欢我就给你买了
If you like it, I'll **just** buy it.

你要是喜欢我就给你买
If you like it, I'll buy it.

---

Answer (score 0):

了【le】
 (aux.v)  used after the verb or adj. to indicate completion
 (int)  1.To strong affirmation
        2.To promote or discourage